# How to have server and clients able to access same files?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, server

I am making a multiplayer web game using create-react-app, socket.io and typescript. I am able to start a server and have players send and receive information from the server. The players connect to the server in a react project, while the server is started in an external file.

However, I now need the server to access files in the react project. E.g. I have a Tile class stored in the tile.ts file inside the react project which players are able to access, but the server cannot. I have tried a lot of different things such as attempting to start the server in the react project, but none of them have been successful as I suppose you cannot run servers from inside the browser.

Right now the only solution I can see is copying the files over from the react project into where the server is located, and then change both instances of the files whenever I want to change the file.

Is there any way for my server to be able to access the same files that the players can access? Also, if this post is lacking in explanation or detail, please tell me.

Comment: Make a third package that has your shared code/types. Turn this into a (private) npm package, and then have your server and client both depend on it.

Comment: #1 What do you mean by "the server is started in an external file."? #2 Why do the backend and frontend need to access tile.ts?

Comment: @JRichardsz I have a seperate react project where I start the server; it isn't started in the react project where the players connect to the server. I want the server to generate the terrain for the game, and to do that it needs to have access to the tile.ts file to create tiles. I can't have the tile.ts file only in the backend as the players need to access it.

Comment: Here's what you do: 1) you send a message from the server to the client with a definition of the terrain you have generated. 2) You let the client render that terrain.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen That's the approach I've been taking, but I don't have a way of the server getting a definition of the generated terrain without having one of the clients generate the terrain and then send it to the server, which I want to avoid.

Comment: If it's just a matter of sharing TypeScript code between client and server, then the solution was already suggested in the first comment to this question...

Comment: @Evert Thanks very much for your response, would you be able to post your response as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to manipulate the part of DOM which is getting generated by tile.ts from server then,

You can add iframe( https://codesandbox.io/s/react-iframe-demo-g3vst-iframe-demo-g3vst ) in tile.ts and then create an api in server which will serve the part which you want, based on your conditions. Add this api into src of iframe. So whenever the DOM will load it will be rendered and based on conditions also you can render.